# 2 Python nested Dictionaries, current data in one the other will fill with the data from the previous minute displays. I need to diff int data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm really new to Python so I hope this makes sense.
These are a sample of 2 dictionaries. What I cannot work out is how to subtract the current entries from the previous entries where the nested dictionary ie "Name2" matches in the previous dictionary.
Also I cannot introduce or use extra libraries.

```
previous = {}

c = []
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.45.09,C_001:2873,C_002:2832,P_002:98.5,C_003:41,P_003:1.4,C_005:1,P_005:0.0,C_010:2873,C_011:8,P_011:0.2,C_012:9,P_012:0.3")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.45.09,C_001:18981,C_002:18683,P_002:98.4,C_003:298,P_003:1.5,C_005:47,P_005:0.2,C_010:18981,C_011:39,P_011:0.2,C_012:86,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.49.09,C_001:3145,C_002:3102,P_002:98.6,C_003:43,P_003:1.3,C_005:1,P_005:0.0,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:3145,C_011:12,P_011:0.3,C_012:13,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.49.09,C_001:20742,C_002:20415,P_002:98.4,C_003:327,P_003:1.5,C_005:54,P_005:0.2,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:20742,C_011:42,P_011:0.2,C_012:96,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.52.30,C_001:3357,C_002:3310,P_002:98.5,C_003:47,P_003:1.4,C_005:2,P_005:0.0,C_007:2,P_007:0.0,C_010:3357,C_011:13,P_011:0.3,C_012:15,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.52.30,C_001:22176,C_002:21823,P_002:98.4,C_003:353,P_003:1.5,C_005:58,P_005:0.2,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:22176,C_011:44,P_011:0.1,C_012:102,P_012:0.4")

def setCMD():

     for cmd in c:
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$                                                        $$$")
       print("$$$             THIS IS THIS THE START                     $$$")
       print("$$$                                                        $$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("Using Command : ",cmd)

     
       zw = dict(item.split(':') for item in cmd.split(',')) 
       
       print("THIS IS ZW ",zw)
       
       modForInter(zw)


def calcDiff(d1,d2):
    print("In Function calDiff")
    for x in d2:
        for y in d1:
            if x==y:
                #print(d1[y],d2[x])
                for i in d1[y]:
                    for i in d2[x]:
                        d1[y][i]=d1[y][i]-d2[x][i]
                        #print(d1[y][i])
                    break
                return d1[y]



def modForInter(zw):
      print("In Mod modForInter")

      global previous
 
      nameDict = {}
      nameDict["Name"] = zw["Name"]
      
      print("This is nameDict",nameDict)
      zw1={ zw["Name"] } 
      print(zw1)                                                               
      
      # List for extraction.
      list1=["Date","Name","Type","C_Time",\
          "C_001","","C_002","P_002","C_003","P_003","C_005","P_005",\
          "C_007","P_007"]
      
      # List for prev
      list2=[
          "C_001","C_002","C_003","C_005","C_007"]
      
      current = {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list1 }
       
      zw = {k: int(v) if isinstance(v, str) and v.isdigit() else v for k, v in zw.items()}

      current = {
      key1 : {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list1 } for key1 in zw1 
      }                                                                                           
      print("current created")
      result = {
      key1 : {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list1 } for key1 in zw1 
      }                                                                                           

      number_of_elements = sum(len(v) for v in current.values())
      if number_of_elements <= 4:
          print("Number of elements is less than 4")
          return
      else:
          print("Number of elements is greater than 4")
          
      y=(str(zw1).replace("{'","").replace("'}",""))
      print(y)  
               
      if "C_001" in previous[y]:
              print("previous is NOT empty")
              print("This is previous_dict :",previous)
              x=calcDiff(current,previous)
              print("This is X",x)
      else:
           print("previous_dict is empty and will be populated")
           previous.update({
      key1 : {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list2 } for key1 in zw1 
      
      })
           print("THIS IS PREVIOUS_DICT : ",previous)
      
      
      del(current)
      del(zw)  
      print("THIS IS RESULT",result)
              


setCMD()
```

Notice that C_007 was added and was not in the previous dictionary and Name2 is gone also.

Comment: Sorry I just can't work out what your function is trying to do, so I'm not able to help make it do what you want. Can you please expand on what you're trying to do exactly? "I need to diff int data" is not particularly intelligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calcDiff()` function seems to be incorrect. I tried running your code but couldn't get your expected output. Hence I modified your code as follows:

```
current =  {'Name2': {'Date': '07Nov2022', 'Name': 'Name2', 'Type': 'stats', 'Time': '12.49.09', 'C_001': 20742, 'C_002': 20415, 'P_002': '98.4', 'C_003': 327, 'P_003': '1.5', 'C_005': 54, 'P_005': '0.2', 'C_007': 1, 'P_007': '0.0'}}

previous = {'Name1': {'C_001': 3145, 'C_002': 3102, 'C_003': 43, 'C_005': 1, 'C_007': 1}, 'Name2': {'C_001': 18981, 'C_002': 18683, 'C_003': 298, 'C_005': 47}}

def calcDiff(d1,d2):
    print("In Function calDiff")
    for x in d2:
        for y in d1:
            if x==y:
                #print(d1[y],d2[x])
                for i in d1[y]:
                    for i in d2[x]:
                        d1[y][i]=d1[y][i]-d2[x][i]
                        #print(d1[y][i])
                    break
                return d1[y]
                

if "C_001" in previous['Name2']:
        print("previous is NOT empty")
        print("This is previous_dict :",previous)
        x=calcDiff(current,previous)
        print(x)
```

I was able to get the result without creating another directory.

```
{'Date': '07Nov2022', 'Name': 'Name2', 'Type': 'stats', 'Time': '12.49.09', 'C_001': 1761, 'C_002': 1732, 'P_002': '98.4', 'C_003': 29, 'P_003': '1.5', 'C_005': 7, 'P_005': '0.2', 'C_007': 1, 'P_007': '0.0'}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked to a degree. The test bit is failing if the "Name2" is not found. I have a more complete code sample that will add.

Comment: Also I incorporated your answer into the code.

Comment: @C.Cab Thanks for the confirmation. Try accepting my answer if it helped! :)

Comment: Can you please have a look again. Like I said I need the Name to be variable.

Answer (score 1):

With the previous answer I was able to complete it.

```
previous = {}

c = []
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.45.09,C_001:2873,C_002:2832,P_002:98.5,C_003:41,P_003:1.4,C_005:1,P_005:0.0,C_010:2873,C_011:8,P_011:0.2,C_012:9,P_012:0.3")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.45.09,C_001:18981,C_002:18683,P_002:98.4,C_003:298,P_003:1.5,C_005:47,P_005:0.2,C_010:18981,C_011:39,P_011:0.2,C_012:86,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.49.09,C_001:3145,C_002:3102,P_002:98.6,C_003:43,P_003:1.3,C_005:1,P_005:0.0,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:3145,C_011:12,P_011:0.3,C_012:13,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.49.09,C_001:20742,C_002:20415,P_002:98.4,C_003:327,P_003:1.5,C_005:54,P_005:0.2,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:20742,C_011:42,P_011:0.2,C_012:96,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name1,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.52.30,C_001:3357,C_002:3310,P_002:98.5,C_003:47,P_003:1.4,C_005:2,P_005:0.0,C_007:2,P_007:0.0,C_010:3357,C_011:13,P_011:0.3,C_012:15,P_012:0.4")
c.append("Date:07Nov22,Name:Name2,Type:InterTerm,C_Time:12.52.30,C_001:22176,C_002:21823,P_002:98.4,C_003:353,P_003:1.5,C_005:58,P_005:0.2,C_007:1,P_007:0.0,C_010:22176,C_011:44,P_011:0.1,C_012:102,P_012:0.4")

def setCMD():

     for cmd in c:
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$                                                        $$$")
       print("$$$             THIS IS THIS THE START                     $$$")
       print("$$$                                                        $$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
       zw = dict(item.split(':') for item in cmd.split(',')) 
       modForInter(zw)

def calcDiff(d1,d2):
    print("In Function calDiff")
    for x in d2:
        for y in d1:
            if x==y:
                #print(d1[y],d2[x])
                for i in d1[y]:
                    for i in d2[x]:
                        d1[y][i]=d1[y][i]-d2[x][i]
                        #print(d1[y][i])
                    break
                return d1[y]

def modForInter(zw):
      print("In Mod modForInter")
      global previous
 
      nameDict = {}
      nameDict["Name"] = zw["Name"]
      
      zw1={ zw["Name"] }                                                             
      
      # List for extraction.
      list1=["Date","Name","Type","C_Time",\
          "C_001","","C_002","P_002","C_003","P_003","C_005","P_005",\
          "C_007","P_007"]
      
      # List for prev
      list2=[
          "C_001","C_002","C_003","C_005","C_007"]
           
      zw = {k: int(v) if isinstance(v, str) and v.isdigit() else v for k, v in zw.items()}
      current = {key1 : {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list1 } for key1 in zw1 }                                                                                           
      result = {}
                                                                                         
      number_of_elements = sum(len(v) for v in current.values())
      if number_of_elements <= 4:
          print("Number of elements is less than 4")
          return
      else:
          print("Number of elements is greater than 4")
          
      y=(str(zw1).replace("{'","").replace("'}",""))
      print(y)  
               
      try:
          YES = previous[y]['C_001']
          result=calcDiff(current,previous)
      except KeyError:
          print('The specified key does NOT exist')
          previous.update({key1 : {key:value for (key,value) in zw.items() if key in list2 } for key1 in zw1 })
           
      del(current)
      del(zw)  
      print("THIS IS RESULT",result)
              
setCMD()
```